# ColorBox doesn't Change Width Dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, colorbox

I am using Jquery `colorbox` plugin at my HTML application. There are two divs at my page. One is at `left` and one is at `right`. I want that. At the beginning `right div's display is none`. When I click somewhere at my left div right `div's display becomes block`. However because of the size of colorbox place second div display's under first div and a scrollbar appears. I don't want that I want it to locate at right I mean `I want colorbox to calculate its width again automatically` (If possible I don't want to declare a width to fix it)

**PS 1:**
My left and right div's css':

```
.left {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

When I don't hide (I use Jquery `.show()`) second div(right div):

> one of is at right other at left.

However when I hide (I use Jquery `.hide()`) second and after I show it (I do `$.colorbox.resize();`) my second div appears at bottom of first one(not at right).

**PS 2:** I get my colorbox content from an external file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colorbox changes its height automatically but doesn't change width. So I did that:

```
$.colorbox.resize({width: pixelValue});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
$.colorbox.resize();
```

Comment: it resizes but still my div is not at right it goes to down. If I don't hide the second div and use colorbox one of is at left and the other is at right.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var contentHeight = $('.class').height();

var contentWidth = $('.class').width();

$.colorbox.resize({ height: contentHeight, width: contentWidth });
```